# How can I use Swagger 2 in Spring Boot 3 (Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-2.0

I have a problem about running Spring Boot 3 with the usage of Swagger 2.

Here are all dependencies used for Swagger 2 in my pom.xml:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Here are the error shown below.

```
java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest not present
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:117) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:125) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.reifyTypeArguments(Reifier.java:68) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:138) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.repository.ClassRepository.computeSuperInterfaces(ClassRepository.java:117) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.repository.ClassRepository.getSuperInterfaces(ClassRepository.java:95) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getGenericInterfaces(Class.java:1250) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.getInterfaces(ResolvableType.java:500) ~[spring-core-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.as(ResolvableType.java:448) ~[spring-core-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.forClass(ResolvableType.java:1048) ~[spring-core-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.plugin.core.config.PluginRegistriesBeanDefinitionRegistrar.getTargetType(PluginRegistriesBeanDefinitionRegistrar.java:101) ~[spring-plugin-core-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.plugin.core.config.PluginRegistriesBeanDefinitionRegistrar.registerBeanDefinitions(PluginRegistriesBeanDefinitionRegistrar.java:71) ~[spring-plugin-core-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar.registerBeanDefinitions(ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar.java:86) ~[spring-context-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.lambda$loadBeanDefinitionsFromRegistrars$1(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:373) ~[spring-context-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:729) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsFromRegistrars(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:372) ~[spring-context-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:148) ~[spring-context-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:120) ~[spring-context-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:410) ~[spring-context-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:283) ~[spring-context-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:344) ~[spring-context-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:115) ~[spring-context-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:745) ~[spring-context-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:565) ~[spring-context-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:432) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1291) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at com.deprem.depremapi.DepremApiApplication.main(DepremApiApplication.java:12) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:495) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:474) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:114) ~[na:na]
    ... 32 common frames omitted
```

How can I fix the issue?

Comment: Springfox and Springdoc are incompatible, use just one of them. I believe Springfox generates an OpenAPI 2.0 (fka Swagger 2.0) definition, whereas Springdoc generates OpenAPI 3.0.

Comment: I deleted Springdoc dependency but I still have an issue.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, springfox is not supported in Spring Boot 3. I recommend you to migrate to springdoc, I also did that, it's simple and supports Swagger 3 too.
https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/3983

Comment: I also added springdoc dependency in pom.xml as you can see.

Comment: But you kept swagger2?

Comment: @S.N Then you should delete the springfox dependencies

Comment: @OctaviaAdler I deleted Springdoc dependency but I still have an issue.

Comment: what I was suggesting is that you use Springdoc instead of Springfox. Springfox is not maintained anymore